# Binarizing column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm trying to binarize a categorical 'Income' column in a Pandas dataframe.

For this column, there are four recorded values: '>50k', '>50k.', '<=50k.', '<=50k'

Currently, my function is...

```
def income_to_numeric(x):
    for val in x:
        if val == '>50k.' or val == '>50k':
            val = 1
        else:
            val = 0
    return x
train['Income'] = income_to_numeric(train['Income'])
```

Obviously, this function and implementation isn't working, but could somebody please explain why this doesn't work? I'm sure this has to do with a fundamental misunderstanding of how functions work or how variables get assigned, but it's not clicking for me just looking my code. I do realize this is not an efficient implementation.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input.

Comment: Also, you said its not working but are you getting any error? or you are not getting desired output? In later case provide sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop actually assigns a copy of the `x` values to the variable `val`, which means that changing `val` won't change the original values at all. Also, it's not healthy to modify the values in place of the array while you are iterating over it.

One possible solution would be to create a new array and then populate it with the desired values, like:

```
def income_to_numeric(x):
    new_x = []
    for val in x:
        if val == '>50k.' or val == '>50k':
            new_x.append(1)
        else:
            new_x.append(0)
    return new_x
```

However, you might want to do something more efficient if your dataframe is quite large. One option would be:

```
binarization = {
    '>50k.': 1,
    '>50k': 1,
    '<=50k.': 0,
    '<=50k': 0,
}
train['New_Income'] = train['Income'].map(binarization)
```

Let us know if this worked for you or if you have further questions

Comment: Thank you so much! The second method you displayed is great.